# Android NDK: How to use deprecated make-standalone-toolchain?

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake, android-ndk

I need to compile a third part lib. I found a tutorial that explains how to do this with the [deprecated make-standalone-toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain).

I am not expert in CMake/C++ compilation and want to follow this tutorial. I don't want to follow the [new method](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems).

Is it possible to install and use make-standalone-toolchain on my Mac that runs Android Studio 2020.3.1 ? How to to do this ? No risk of corrupting my dev environment ?

Thanks

Comment: [Top of the "standalone toolchain" documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain): "As of r19, the NDK's default toolchains are standalone toolchains, which renders this process unnecessary." The "new method" effectively skips the step that creates a copy of the toolchain and allows you to use the prebuilt binaries directly from the NDK. So: what stops you from doing that? I suggest you edit your question and ask how to fix that instead.

Comment: Oh, this is colloquially known as an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Here is my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69673741/how-to-build-assimp-for-android Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.