# How to build Assimp for Android?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, assimp

I am trying to build a .so lib of the C++ lib [Assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp), for Android.

The explanations on GitHub are very unclear and outdated.

Any idea about how to do that ? A detailed tutorial would be great :)

Comment: Same way you cross-compile any CMake-based library: specify the CMake Toolchain file included with the NDK and [set the Android ABI and API level](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake)

Comment: I am a newbie on these topics. I have no clue how to 'cross-compile any CMake-based library'. If you can give more details about how to do in this specific case, would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: See the "Usage -> commandline" part of the link I pasted.

Comment: _"...The explanations on GitHub are very unclear and outdated..._ did you click the documentation link [The Asset-Importer-Lib Documentation](https://assimp-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ?  Which contains [The Android build](https://assimp-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/quickstart.html#the-android-build)

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy because `Assimp` is a `cmake` based project.

So adapt your `NDK` path and other variables in the following script and run it from project root folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

ANDROID_ABI=x86
ANDROID_NDK=/home/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858
ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-29

mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
      -DANDROID_ABI=$ANDROID_ABI \
      -DANDROID_PLATFORM=$ANDROID_PLATFORM \
      -DASSIMP_ANDROID_JNIIOSYSTEM=ON \
      ..
make
```

or simply run as separate commands from the shell.